# Control camera from Visio 16 VBA

Tags: vba, excel, visio

I found a snippet of code for taking a photo with the webcam using microsoft Excel:

```
CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1764).Execute
```

I'd very much like to use this in Visio, which we'll be using to take photos on tablets.  I've searched the code, but can find nothing in the Vision msdn documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765940.aspx

or the object browser in commandbuttons.  I can't find (don't know how to find) the name of the control in Excel.  Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: `CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1764).caption` will tell you.

Comment: That's giving me a compile error: Invalid property?

Comment: You need to show it using either a `Msgbox` or `Debug.Print` statement - eg: `Msgbox CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1764).caption`

Comment: .... Oh god... its been a long day...
(Thanks)